# Pointers to an Array and Vector object

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, c++11, vector

How do pointers work for an array and a vector object

**For array_1**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using namespace std;
int main(){
int a[3][4]={0,1,3,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11};
//int (*pi)[4]=a;

for( auto *pi=a; pi!=a+3; ++pi ){
  for( auto p=*pi; p!=*pi + 4; ++p){
       cout << *p << "\n";
  }
}

}
```

**For array_2**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using namespace std;
int main(){
int a[3][4]={0,1,3,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11};
//int (*pi)[4]=a;

for( auto pi=a; pi!=a+3; ++pi ){
  for( auto p=*pi; p!=*pi + 4; ++p){
       cout << *p << "\n";
  }
}

}
```

**For vector_1**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
int main(){
vector<int>  a{0,1,3,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11};

for(auto i=a.begin(); i!=a.end(); ++i ){
  // we can also use begin(a) and end(a)
       cout << *i << "\n";
  }
}
```

**For vector_2**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
int main(){
vector<int>  a{0,1,3,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11};

for(auto *i=a.begin(); i!=a.end(); ++i ){
  // we can also use begin(a) and end(a)
       cout << *i << "\n";
}
}
```

Both codes (for array_1 and for array_2) give the same output i.e (0-11)
you can see that there is a difference in the first for loop of both pieces of code.
In the **For vector_1** ,as far as I understood, I think, I am creating a pointer `i` to the beginning of the vector and then dereferencing it to fetch the value of that corresponding  position. Now my doubt is, how come in the **For array_1** and **For array_2** when I use the `*pi` in the 2nd for loop, instead of getting dereferenced(like in the case of vector), it is fetching me the iterative values?
And why does the **For vector_2** not work the same way as **For vector_1**?

And what is the return type of the `size()` and `begin()/end()` function for vector?
Cause when I use **for(decltype(a.size()) i=0; i!=end(); ++i)**, it is giving me a type conversion error.

The code **for array_1, for array_2 and for vector_1** gives the same output(0-10). It is the **for vector_2** that is giving an error. 
Thanks.

Comment: You aren't using `std::array<>`?

Comment: does't make any difference i am getting right output for both that code(using namesapace std),

Comment: I really recommend not using the `auto` keyword if you're not confident in what is returned by a function. `a.begin()` returns an iterator, which has `operator *` overloaded to give the value of the element it's pointing to. As far as example 2 goes, you're not supposed to use an asterisk after you use the `auto` keyword-- it defeats the purpose of the `auto` keyword, which tells the compiler to `auto`matically deduce the type.

Comment: Besides auto, const auto& and auto&, i can not see any useful implication of auto*

Comment: even if i am not using the asterisk it seems like I should be getting the element values which the iterator is pointing but thats not happening here i am getting an error there.
  for(decltype(a.size()) i=0; i!=a.end(); ++i ) gives error while for(decltype(a.size()) i=0; i!=10; ++i ) works just fine. so whats the real difference here

Comment: `a.size()` returns an unsigned int. `a.end()` returns an iterator. The two are incompatible types.

Comment: Oh... Thanks. now how do I upvote your comment... any idea about what the problem with the 4th code.

Comment: Also, using `decltype(...)` is not recommended unless you're doing relatively complex template meta-programming or function binding. (You're not). @DieterLücking basically told you why the vector 2 example is wrong. You NEVER use `auto *`, only `auto`, `auto &`, and `const auto &`. I recommend NEVER using the auto keyword until you are much more familiar with the STL, and how to manipulate it.

Comment: @user3232918 _'does't make any difference'_ I'm afraid you have misunderstood what I was saying. I meant: You don't have any instances `std::array<std::array<int,3>,4>` in your code. So why are you doing `#include <array>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of **vector_1** you are not creating a pointer, but an **iterator** - in most basic use cases, like printing vector results, iterator works and is used like a pointer, but it is not the same and shouldn't be handled the same way you handle a pointer. In case of **vector_2** you do something nasty since this is the job of the **auto** keyword to determine whether the variable is to be a pointer or not.

The last example causes an error, because you are trying to create a **pointer to iterator**, and the type returned by the **begin()** function is an **iterator** (a value), not **the address of the iterator object**.

If you want to know the return types of functions like **size()**, **begin()**, etc. you can always refer to one of the several large C++ reference websites, for example:

www.cplusplus.com

www.cppreference.com

Comment: The &a.begin() leaves you with the address of a temporary.

Comment: Oh, that's right. VS 2012 didn't complain about this for some reason. I've removed that part from the answer.

Comment: Taking the address of a temporary is a `MSVC` extension, IIRC with `/W4` it may issue a warning.